# How to get an array field from Firestore and write in struct field in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, struct, google-cloud-firestore

The problem that I faced is, I can reach every field in Firestore and write in structs except array&map field.

My firestore data is something like:

```
 let data : [String : Any] = [
                "name" : "House A",
                "price" : 2000,
                "contents" : [
                   "water" : true,
                   "internet" : false
                ]
            ]
```

Here is getDocument function:

```
let docRef = db.collection("example").document("example")

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {

                let data = Houses(Doc: document)
                ...
                ...
                ...
            } else {
                print(error, "Item not found")
            }
        }
```

Here is my structs :

```
struct Houses {
    var name: String?
    var price: Int
    var contents : Contents

    init(Doc: DocumentSnapshot){

        self.name = Doc.get("name") as? String ?? ""
        self.price = Doc.get("price") as! Int
        self.contents = Doc.get("contents") as! Contents
    }
}

struct Contents  {
    var water: Bool
    var internet : Bool

    init?(data: [String: Any]) {

        guard let water = data["water"] as? Bool,
            let internet = data["internet"] as? Bool else {
                return nil
        }

        self.water = water
        self.internet = internet

    }
}
```

The other version of Contents :

```
struct Contents  {
    var water: Bool
    var internet : Bool

    init(Doc: DocumentSnapshot){
        self.water = Doc.get("water") as! Bool
        self.internet = Doc.get("internet") as! Bool
    }
}
```

UPDATED 
The problem solved with changing this line:

```
self.contents = Doc.get("contents") as! Contents
```

to;

```
self.contents = Contents(data: Doc.get("contents") as! [String : Any])
```

**name** and **price** returns what I expected but **contents** always return **nil**. I tried to configure **Contents** but results are same.  I think, I have to configure struct named **Contents**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: self.contents = Contents(Doc.get("contents"))

Comment: @SachinVas Yeah that was the problem. Thank you so much!!